# Field due to bound charges in matter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, polarization

What is the field due to a long cylinder that carries uniform polarization perpendicular to the axis? 
I am not able to get the answer using the expressions for the surface bound charge density and volume bound charge density(I keep getting zero as the answer).